# Workflow - Copying record from one list to another

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list

SP 2013

I have a list set up called FE1, the user adds a new item, saves it and the data goes via a workflow into another list FE2.

The workflow is a s follows

IF Current Item:FE1 is not empty
Copy Item in Current Item to FE2

This works. The problem is if the user goes back edits a record in FE1 and saves. Instead of updating the same record in FE2 it creates a new record in FE2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new field called `ItemAlreadyCopied` - make it a choice field, with the values Yes and No.  If you like, you can set the default value to No.

Then, after your existing line:

IF Current Item:FE1 is not empty Copy Item in Current Item to FE2

add this:

SET `ItemAlreadyCopied` to Yes.

This will stop it creating duplicate records.

### Further Info

Ensure you understand how the Workflow Start Options affect a workflow.  Another solution for you would be to modify the start options so that your workflow only runs once - when a new item is created.

[image: start options]

You might need to add to your workflow, or perhaps it is easier to make an additional one, if you want items in FE2 to be updated when FE1 is modified.  I would make a separate workflow with the Start Option '...when an item is changed'.